# How to show confirm box before submit form in moodle on course edit page?

Tags: forms, moodle

I am using moodle 2.8

I wants to confirm user before edit course.

Basically I have a category name ex. 'Live' category

So when user move course into 'Live' category then want to show confirm box and if he click on yes then course will be update otherwise redirect to course edit page.

Answer (score 0):

This will require changes to the Moodle core code (not usually a great idea, for ongoing maintenance) and would probably be a bit fiddly to implement - you would need to store all the submitted details somewhere in the confirmation form, then re-send them along with the confirmation.

It might be easier to make a small core code change to prevent the user from ever moving the course directly into the 'live' category (adjust the 'validation' function in the form submission), then have a separate admin page (within a local plugin, or maybe a block), that listed all the non-live courses and gave the option of moving them into the 'live' category (with the appropriate warnings / confirm action).